# using enum to select gender is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would appreciate any help. I'm using enum to select the gender between male and female. But is not working, is returning female but not male, it appears empty. And when I go to the edit section it doesn't show male or female as selected.

When I go the rails console and I type gender.enum? it returns true or false.

[image]

That's my Customer model

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  enum gender: [:female, :male]
end
```

That's what I have in the _form.html.erb

```
    <%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "male") %>
    <%= label_tag(:gender_male,   "Male") %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:gender, "female") %>
    <%= label_tag(:gender_female, "Female") %>
```

The gender was in boolean before, then I changed it to integer in order to use  enum

```
class ChangeGenderData < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
change_column :customers, :gender, :integer

  end
end
```

Here is an image of what appears

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using this code.

```
<%= form.collection_radio_buttons :gender, Customer.genders, :first, :first %>
```